# E-Commerce Open Source em ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, framework, e-commerce, código-aberto

Eu sei que em PHP tem muito framework para e-commerce no mercado atualmente, mas em ASP.NET, quais framework hoje existem? Quais vantagens e desvantagens de cada um?

Será que vale a pena utiliza ou construir do zero?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você precisa analisar qual a caracteristica do seu projeto para fazer a escolha certa, opções há. Vou postar opções, algumas opensource.

- http://www.nopcommerce.com/
- https://www.smartstore.com/en/net
- http://www.dotshoppingcart.com/ http://www.aspdotnetstorefront.com/
- http://www.kartris.com http://www.opencart.com
- http://www.woocommerce.com/

Há outros fechados como VirtoCommerce, UCommerce, TeaCommerce e uWebShop

Se pesquisar também encontrará gerenciadores de conteúdos, CMS, que tem o poder e recursos para montar um e-commerce.

Comment: Adiciona o MusicStore https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore

Comment: Pablo.. a MusicStore passa longe de ser uma plataforma real de ecommerce. 

Gilberto.. o WooCommerce é feito para o Wordpress em PHP.

Comment: Nunca usei com wordpress, mas pelo jeito é possível. Veja o que tem no site deles: "You've built sites using WordPress already - so why not use the platform you already understand and extend it with WooCommerce to build an online store too?"
Recomendo pesquisar mais sobre para ter certeza se é a melhor opção para seu caso. Entre em contato com eles